# Vector form of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, parametric

> Express the following plane in vector form:
>
> $\mathcal P_1\subseteq  \Bbb R^3$ with equation $4x-z=0$.

The answer is $t(1,0,4)+s(0,1,0)$.
I don't understand how they got $(0,1,0)$ for the direction vector.

Comment: Both $(1,0,4), (0,1,0)$ are on the plane. Now an arbitrary point on the same plane can be written as a linear combination of these two points.

Comment: can (0,0,0) be the answer instead of (0,1,0) ??

Comment: @SumantaDas That method is incorrect *if* $(0,0,0)$ is not on the plane.

Comment: You need two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: @player3236  $\mathcal P_1$ contains $(0,0,0)$. I have not written any general method; in other words, just keeping in mind any $2$-dimensional vector space is a span of two linearly independent vectors of it. I know this does not work for any hyperplane.

Comment: wait so can (0,0,0) be one of the answers?

Comment: A plane in vector form is $\vec p + s \vec v + t \vec w$, where $\vec p$ is a point on the plane and $\vec v, \vec w$ are two linearly independent vectors on the plane. It happens that $\vec p = (0,0,0)$ was chosen. However $(0,0,0)$ cannot be one of $\vec v, \vec w$, since any set of vectors containing the zero vector is not linearly independent.

Comment: @player3236 based on your explanation, can t(0,1,0)+s(1,0,4) be the answer instead of t(1,0,4)+s(0,1,0) ?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @kimwow Of course; $s$ and $t$ have no specific meaning, so the vectors are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

The cartesian equation is $z=4x$

The parametrization is not unique. Anyway You need two *linearly independent* points on the plane.

One point can be $A=(1,0,4)$. The second one cannot be $(2,0,8)$ or other  points you can get from $A$ multiplying by a constant. Otherwise you get a line not a plane.

The second point cannot obviously be $(0,0,0$.

So we look for a point where the only nonzero coordinate is $y$, like $(0,1,0)$ or $(0,10,0)$

Finally the parametric equation of the plane is
$$(1,0,4)t+(0,1,0)s=0$$

Note that $(2,0,8)t+(0,10,0)s=0$ would be right.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi\equiv 4x-z=0$ be your plane. We notice that the point $(0,0,0)\in\pi$ and the orthogonal vector to the plane is $\underline u=(4,0,-1)$.
The vector space $\text{dir}(\pi)$ has dimension $2$ and the vectors that span this space are orthogonal to the vector $\underline u$.
We can take for example the vectors $\underline v=(1,0,4)$ and $\underline w=(0,1,0)$, infact we have $$\langle\underline u,\underline v\rangle=1\cdot4+0+4\cdot(-1)=0\implies\text{ they are orthogonal}$$
$$\langle\underline u,\underline w\rangle=0\cdot4+1\cdot0+0\cdot(-1)=0\implies\text{ they are orthogonal}$$
Finally the equation of the plane $\pi$ is$$\begin{cases}x=0+\alpha\\y=0+\beta\\z=0+4\alpha \end{cases},\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R.$$